# How do you list all tables used to create a view in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do you list all tables used to create a view in BigQuery?
In MSSQL/TSQL, you can use this code to list them for example.

```
select distinct schema_name(v.schema_id) as schema_name,
   v.name as view_name,
   schema_name(o.schema_id) as referenced_schema_name,
   o.name as referenced_entity_name,
   o.type_desc as entity_type
from sys.views v
join sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
 on d.referencing_id = v.object_id
 and d.referenced_id is not null
join sys.objects o
 on o.object_id = d.referenced_id
where o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' 
 order by schema_name,
      view_name;
```

-- However, I'm not able to recreate a such as code in BigQuery.

I know in BigQuery you can get the DDL of a view using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS but neither seem to have the dependencies in them.

Only way I can think of doing this at the moment in BigQuery is to write a parser to identify the first and second ` marks after the FROM and JOIN statements and put them in a table, but that seems too complicated for a simple task. Thought I'd ask here, hoping there is a better way to write this.

Analyzed the Information Schema tables on BigQuery to try and get similar results to my MSSQL/TSQL statement

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select table_source, concat(table_catalog,".",table_schema,".",view_name) 
as view_name,
from(
select  table_catalog,
table_schema,
table_name as view_name,
view_definition as query, 
ARRAY_CONCAT(
   regexp_extract_all(view_definition, r"YOUR-PROJECT-1[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+") ,
   regexp_extract_all(view_definition, r"YOUR-PROJECT-2[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+"),
   regexp_extract_all(view_definition, r"YOUR-PROJECT-3[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+") 
    )
 as table_source,
 FROM `region-YOUREGION.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` 
) ,
UNNEST(table_source ) table_source
```